# JSON from api not being displayed on ReactJS render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am pretty new to ReactJS and am trying to figure out why I am not able to display the fetched data. Checked the data in Postman and it is as expected so I am sure there is something syntactical I am missing. I didnt put the key value in this post.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Stockstuff extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          error: null,
          isLoaded: false,
          items: []
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=TSLA&apikey=???")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: result.items
              });
            },

            (error) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error : true
              });
            }
          )
      }


      render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (error) {
          return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
          return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
          return (
            <ul>
              {items.map(item => (
                <li key={item.name}>
                  {item.name} {item.price}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          );
        }
      }
}

export default Stockstuff
```

**What is the fault?**

Comment: Your code is correct, but the URL API just returns `error`.

Comment: @AmerllicA, the apikey in the query string is replaced by `???`. @Ross Lamon, What is the expected payload?

Comment: @AmerllicA, how can you possibly know that the code is correct? What if items is not an iterable?

Comment: Dear @entiendoNull, exactly right, I assume the `items` exist on the response and it is an iterable object. The code is correct. the issue is not about ReactJS.

Comment: **NEVER** email your code to someone who appears to be trying to help.

Comment: Thanks @IanKemp to this hint.

Comment: Well, whether the code is right or not depends completely on the data structure of `items`. From the information provided there is no way of knowing if the piece of code responsible to render the `items` works as intended or not.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint returns an object, not an array, that's why you can't `map` over it.

I open this URL from code `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=TSLA&apikey=???`

Although it’s strange that it works with `apikey=???` for me and I can see something like:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Monthly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "TSLA",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-02-21",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Monthly Time Series": {
        "2020-02-21": {
            "1. open": "673.6900",
            "2. high": "968.9899",
            "3. low": "673.5200",
            "4. close": "901.0000",
            "5. volume": "377921898"
        },
        "2020-01-31": {
            "1. open": "424.5000",
            "2. high": "653.0000",
            "3. low": "421.7100",
            "4. close": "650.5700",
            "5. volume": "407621638"
        },
        [...]
    }
}
```

I slightly changed the code to match the data and everything seems fine:

https://codesandbox.io/s/red-mountain-ipn3h

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the api endpoint and the structure of the data has no `items` key. So when you say `results.items` it's not returning anything. It looks like the two top-level keys for the object that is returned are `"Meta Data"` and `"Monthly Time Series"`. You can't use dot notation for keys with spaces, so assuming you want the `"Monthly Time Series"` data, you'd want to do:

```
          ...

          .then(
            (result) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: result["Monthly Time Series"]
              });
            },

          ...
```

ETA: it also doesn't return an array so you won't be able to use `.map` in your render function.

Comment: You pass half way.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Stockstuff extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          error: null,
          isLoaded: false,
          items: []
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=TSLA&apikey=???")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: Object.entries(result['Monthly Time Series'])
              });
            },

            (error) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error : true
              });
            }
          )
      }


      render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (error) {
          return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
          return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
          return (
            <ul>
              {items.map(item => (
                <li key={item[0]}>
                  <span>{item[1].open}</span>
                  <span>{item[1].high}</span>
                  <span>{item[1].low}</span>
                  <span>{item[1].close}</span>
                  <span>{item[1].volume}</span>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          );
        }
      }
}

export default Stockstuff;
```

Comment: Hey, you just posted a "slightly changed" version of my code from codesendbox example. Is this okay on StackOverflow? 

Comment: Dear comrade @artanik, I didn't see your code yet. I just write my sight. If you think I steal your codes, please flag my post and report it. But I swear I didn't see your link yet.

Comment: I won't flag your answer, apparently `Object.entries` is an obvious answer to this question and you also came up with this idea, and that's totally fine :)